# AW3D30: DSM file is grayscale 32 bits?

Tags: dem

I downloaded multiple areas in AW3D30, but each time, the DSM file is 32 bit (instead of 16 as indicated in the specs), and the 32 bits are grayscale with the alpha channel always to 255. (I'll be using red, green, blue and alpha to talk about each of the 4 bytes)

This is very weird, as elevation from 0m to 3000m is indicated by the red, green and blue channel going from 0 to 11.

Also, it seems that voids in the data are set to white (255) as opposed to -9999 (as indicated in the specs).

Can someone used to AW3D30 help me out?

I used the official website : https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/data/index.htm